# How to call two methods in same class?

Tags: java, function, inheritance, methods, overloading

How can I call two methods from the same class over one object? I mean I try to write a class and its methods to run above code:

```
volume = Calculate.do_calc().get_volume(a);
```

I am creating Calculate class and two methods of it. do_calc() and get_volume(a). How should I write this class to run that code.

Comment: its depends on many things, like is your method static? what is return type of methods?

Comment: Their return type is float.

Comment: are they static? and both have same return type ?

Comment: They are not static.Yes they have same return type.do_calc() method will have more than one, get_volume() methods. I think i will overload the get_volume() method. But I didn't understand how can I call two methods of same class in one line.

Comment: refer my anser , if both have same return type its not possible to call in one line

Answer (score 0):

You must `return this;` at the end of each method of your class if they are not `static`. If the methods are `static`, do it like this:

```
public class Calculation {
     public static Calculation do_calc () {
           //do your calculation
          return null;
      }

     public static Calculation get_volume(int x) {
           //do your calculation
          return null;
      }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
Calculation.do_calc().get_volume(1);
```

No problem in returning `null`, as the methods are static and not related to a specific instance of the class. If you don't like it, then `return new Calculation();`

[Edit]

The first method should return a real object if you need to pass its result to the second method:

```
public class Calculation {

     int result;

     public static Calculation do_calc () {
           //do your calculation
           Calculation c=new Calculation();
           c.result = theResultOfTheCalculation;
          return c;
      }

     public void get_volume(int x) {
           //do your calculation for example:
           System.out.println(result + x);
      }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be a `static` method, in which case `do_calc()` would need to be a static factory method. Not quite as simple as `return this`...

Comment: But he says " over one objects"! @BoristheSpider

Comment: This is a rookie Java programmer, don't read so much into the words. Look at the syntax - it looks much more like a `static` method than an instance one - to me at least.

Comment: Now it is not @BoristheSpider

Comment: I think i was wrong, i said they aren't static but i learned it now. To call a method without creating an object , the method should be static ? Then i should make the methods static.Correct me please if I am wrong

Comment: Right. In order to call a method without creating an object, the method needs to be `static`. I will update my answer with a small example.

Comment: Thanks.My last question is , if they are returning null , how can I get my calculation result from the function ?

Comment: In this case, the `do_calc` method should return an object that contains the result. I will update the answer accordingly. @RasimGuler

Answer (score 0):

Unless do_calc() returns the class in where de function get_volume() is located this should never be done.

Comment: `s/should never/cannot/g`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little sample for you.

```
public class ChainTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println(new ChainTest().do_calc().get_volume(1));
        }

        public ChainTest do_calc() {
                // do something;
                return ChainTest.this;
        }

        public int get_volume(int a) {
                return a;
        }
}
```

Comment: `s/ChainTest.this/this/g`

Comment: @BoristheSpider - What have you commented here? I didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write the code in one line. You can call same object methods in different lines.

```
Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
calculator.do_calc();
calculator.get_volume(a);
```

In case, if you want static methods

```
Calculator.do_calc();
Calculator.get_volume(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1 If do_calc is static**

```
public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Calculator.do_calc().get_volume(1));
    }

    public static Calculator do_calc() {

        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        // do something;

        return calculator;
    }

    public float get_volume(int a) {
        return a;
    }
}
```

**Case 2 : If do_calc is not static**

```
public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Calculator().do_calc().get_volume(1));
    }

    public Calculator  do_calc() {

        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        // do something;

        return calculator;
    }

    public float get_volume(int a) {
        return a;
    }
}
```

**Case  3 : If both have return type float as you mentioned in comment**

```
public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        calculator.do_calc();
        System.out.println(calculator.get_volume(1));
    }

    public float do_calc() {

        // do something;

        return 1f; // return your result
    }

    public float get_volume(int a) {
        // do something;
        return a;
    }
}
```